# Help with Permutations

Tags: programming, combinatorics, permutation, debugging

I am currently trying to generate a list of permutations of length 2 of elements of a list of strings. For example:

```
Permutations[{"s1", "s2", "s3", "s4"}, {2}]
{{"s1", "s2"}, {"s1", "s3"}, {"s1", "s4"}, {"s2", "s1"}, {"s2", "s3"}, {"s2", "s4"}, {"s3", "s1"}, {"s3", "s2"}, {"s3", "s4"}, {"s4", "s1"}, {"s4", "s2"}, {"s4", "s3"}}
```

which is quite correct.

Now, my problem starts when attempting the same operation for a really big list of strings imported from a tsv file - we are talking of a bit more than 10000 strings. All sort of characters can be expected in strings.

This is the code that I am using:

```
t1 = Import["/home/bla/work/parsed_names.tsv"]
t2 = Table[t1[[i]][[1]], {i, 1, Length[t1]}]
Permutations[t2, {2}]
```

After evaluation of the last line, I get no output. If I evaluate it twice, all the symbols defined previously (t1, t2) become undefined, and Permutations finally give this output:

```
Permutations[t2, {2}]
Permutations::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Permutations[t2,{2}]. >>
Permutations[t2, {2}]
```

Which is the output for an undefined value of t2.

I tried to debug the problem: the import operations seems to go fine, each element of t2 is a proper string:

```
Length[t2]
10525

Tally[Table[Head[t2[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[t2]}]]
{{String, 10525}}
```

I tried running Trace to understand what is going on, but Mathematica still kept quiet during the first evaluation. The second evaluation again forces all the symbols to be cleared, and the output of Trace is unhelpful:

```
{Permutations[t2,{2}], {Message[Permutations::normal,1,Permutations[t2,{2}]],
 {MakeBoxes[Permutations::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Permutations[t2,{2}]. >>,StandardForm],
  RowBox[{StyleBox[RowBox[{Permutations,::,normal}],MessageName],: ,
   "Nonatomic expression expected at position \!\(1\) in \!\(Permutations[\(\(t2, \(\({2}\)\)\)\)]\). \!\(\*ButtonBox[\">>\", ButtonStyle->\"Link\", 
    ButtonFrame->None, ButtonData:>\"paclet:ref/message/General/normal\", ButtonNote -> \"Permutations::normal\"]\)"}]},Null},Permutations[t2,{2}]}
```

Is there something obviously wrong that I am doing? If not, how can I debug this problem further?

Comment: Can you upload the tsv file compressed?

Comment: If you simply type, "t1" and hit shift + enter, what does mms show?

Comment: @Mike: unfortunately I cannot

Comment: Look at how it scales: `ListLogLogPlot@Table[{i, Length[Permutations[Range[i], {2}]]}, {i,10^Range[1, 3., .2]}]` gives [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Pu0s5.png). It's probably related (but I don't see exactly what is happening)

Comment: Have you run a cpu monitor while doing this? It helps sometimes to see if the kernel is still running.

Comment: @DavidCarraher: after import, mathematica shows correct partial output, together with the note "A very large output was generated"

Comment: @rcollyer it sounds like it dies, but then how does the trace continue?

Comment: @paolo and what does it show after the error? it's empty right?

Comment: I just did a test: if I reduce the size of the data to 1/10 then Permutations work. Tried also with 1/2, but that did not work.

Comment: @acl: what error are you referring to? the case when mathematica just does not output anything is devoid of any further text.

Comment: @acl I meant as a separate process like the task manager on windows or the activity monitor on MacOS. But, I agree with you, it sounds like it dies. However, this provides a way to ensure that it is dieing and not just going incommunicado.

Comment: @rcollyer yes, I had misunderstood something in the question

Comment: @paolo, keep an eye on the `In[]` values for your inputs. If it resets to `In[1]` you know the Kernel has quit and restarted.

Comment: @SimonWoods, I am not really sure what the In values are, but I have verified with Activity Monitor that MathKernel dies when the dataset is too big.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps I misunderstood, but look at how many elements there should have been in your list:

`ListLogLogPlot@Table[{i, Length[Permutations[Range[i], {2}]]}, {i,10^Range[1, 3., .2]}]` [image: Mathematica graphics]

It sounds like your kernel quits when you try to calculate the permutations.

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe you may be correct. The fact that the symbols gets undefined at the second evaluation could point towards a kernel restart.

Comment: @paolo If memory serves me right, then the number of permutations you are trying to produce is `Binomial[10000,2]` which is roughly 5*10^7, not counting ordering. It's not very suprising that Mathematica is not happy finding all of them. Just crashing the Kernel is kindof rude though...